# XMLHttpRequest in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

I am very new to jQuery and need help here. I have been using XMLHttpRequest in JavaScript which calls a WCF service for further processing. This service doesn't return anything. Just takes a parameter and process different different modules.

```
    function CallMathsService(str) {
    xmlhttp = null;
    var url = "http://localhost/Maths/" + str;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText != null) {
        alert("Success.");
            }

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

I need to re-write this in jQuery. Can someone please help?

Comment: have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: and http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: then if you are facing some specific issues post it

Comment: Many thanks for replying. However I was making one silly mistake; have been creating a html file and forgot to add the following script tag.

       <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These do very much the same thing.

jQuery.ajax() -> https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
jQuery.get() -> https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Many thanks for replying. However I was making one silly mistake; have been creating a html file and forgot to add the following script tag. <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery

```
{ xhr: function () {
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            xhr.onprogress = function (evt) {
                // For downloads
                alert("test");
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                    percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                    $('.myprogress').text(percentComplete + '%');
                    $('.myprogress').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                }
            };
            return xhr;
        },
}
```